# Change jquery-ui modal window color/image effect/overlay

Tags: css, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Is there a way to change the dark background color that jquery-ui adds to the modal div?

**EDIT:**

Found it, only need to edit the background color and the opacity of:

```
.ui-widget-overlay{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit

```
.ui-widget-overlay{
     background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by changing default css provided in

Here you can change color :

```
  .ui-widget-content{
      border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  }
```

Just go to the jquery.ui.theme.css file you will find this css

Comment: i mean the dark effect arround the window

Comment: I did not see any dark effect around the window

Comment: er... no? what about the dark effect that doesn't let you click anywhere into the page but to the modal window?